# How do I remote into a Centos box with Powershell running a sudo command?

Tags: powershell, centos

I am trying to connect to a remote Linux VM (CentOS) using PowerShell 5.x.  My code works fine for commands NOT requiring sudo (root) privileges.  For sudo privileged commands (i.e. `ls -la /root`) the script requests me to provide a password interactively via the keyboard - not what I need.

On my CentOS box I enabled my user to run sudo commands without providing a password - this works fine in the VM (I can do a `ls -la /root` without providing sudo password), but not when remoting in using PuTTY or Powershell.

This is my PowerShell code (I tried with/without `-pw` parameter):

```
&($plinkpath + "plink.exe")  $username@$servername $command
&($plinkpath + "plink.exe") -pw $password $username@$servername $command
```

I expect PuTTY and PowerShell to allow me to login without providing a password. This is the error I get:

```
plink.exe : -- Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server: ------------------
At D:\\SSHToRemoteLinux.ps1:9 char:1
+ &($plinkpath + "plink.exe") -pw $password $username@$servername $comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (-- Keyboard-int...---------------:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

-- End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server ---------------------------
```

Comment: Add `-batch` to disable interactive prompts. Also, how did you enable your user to run `sudo` without password?

Comment: Do you still need this? I can provide you with a different method to connect.